# How to handle onChange ReactJs? Details inside cant explain in question

Tags: reactjs, frontend, user-input

Hi I have a problem in react user input text. I have a list of items together with an input text.
When i typed inside the first input, all input boxes changes. how to deal with this.

example code

```
handleEditChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event.target.name)
        console.log(event.target.value)
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
    };


{items.map(item=> (
  <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light" placeholder="Reply" name="reply" value= 
  {this.state.reply} onChange={this.handleChange} />
))}
```

So the input box will repeat based on the loop, for example it will be 3 input boxes. picture sample

[image]

How can i prevent this? thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `<input ... name={item.name} value={this.state[item.name]}>` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have separate state variables for each input value. You're currently looping through your items and rendering an identical input for each, with the same value being `this.state.reply`.

According to the picture you attached, you could wrap each input in a `Discussion` component which would take care of handling only one input at a time.

Comment: how can i do that, im having trouble in my setState when i change the name of the name={"reply" + item.id}